# Consulta estoque, retorno null access

Tags: vb.net

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Estrutura]

Meu código:

```
Private Sub CarregaEstoque()
    Using con As OleDbConnection = GetConnection()
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT IdProduto, Descricao, (SELECT SUM(Entradas.QtdEntrada) FROM Entradas WHERE Entradas.IdProduto = Produtos.IdProduto) - " & _
                                "(SELECT SUM(Saidas.QtdSaida) FROM Saidas WHERE Saidas.IdProduto = Produtos.IdProduto) AS Diferenca FROM Produtos"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Como retornar a quantidade do produto 02, sendo que não teve saídas referidas a este?

Comment: Já tentou usar Coalesce na sua sql? na select de saidas, se não retornar nenhum valor o retorno passa a ser 0, e o cálculo vai funcionar. não sei a sintaxe do seu banco, mas geralmente é algo assim Coalesce(suaselect, 0).

Comment: Tentei usar "SELECT IdProduto, Descricao, (SELECT SUM(Entradas.QtdEntrada) FROM Entradas WHERE Entradas.IdProduto = Produtos.IdProduto) - " & _ "(SELECT COALESCENSE (SUM(Saidas.QtdSaida, 0)) FROM Saidas WHERE Saidas.IdProduto = Produtos.IdProduto) AS Diferenca FROM Produtos" mas retornou o erro: Número incorreto de argumentos usados com a funcão na expressão de consulta

Comment: Tenta mudar o seu select: (SELECT COALESCENSE (SUM(Saidas.QtdSaida), 0)), veja se funciona.